# Strong version of the Number Avoidance Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

I am currently reading the book *Combinatorial Game Theory* by Aaron Siegel. I tried to solve Problem 3.10 in Chapter II, which is a stronger form of the Number Avoidance Theorem:

> Suppose $x$ is equal to a number and $G$ is not, and let $H$ be an arbitrary game. If left has a winning move of the form $G + H + x^L$, then she has a winning move of the form $G^L + H + x$.

I tried to solve this on my own, but failed so far. If $x$ is not just equal to a number but actually *is* a number, then the statement is clear by comparing incentives of $x$ and $G$. I tried to solve the general case by reducing $x$ to canonical form step-by-step. This worked fine as long as the option $x^L$ from the statement is not reversible. If it is reversible, I do not see any way to proceed.

Does anyone know of a better method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement from Siegel's book is false. Here is a counterexample:

Let $G \equiv {\uparrow}$, $H \equiv *2$, and $x \equiv * + * = 0$. Then $G + H + x^L \equiv {\uparrow} + *2 + * = {\uparrow}{*}3 > 0$ is a win for Left. If the statement from the problem were true, there would be a left option $G^L$ such that $G^L + H + x \ge 0$. However, $G^L + H + x \equiv 0 + *2 + (* + *) = *2 \not\gtrless 0$.

Comment: Good job finding the counterexample! Someone should email Aaron Siegel. I would, but I cannot find his contact information online.

Comment: Found his mail address and sent him a mail