# Book Recommendations for CGT

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

Could someone recommend books on Combinatorial Game Theory suitable for self-study and beginners (the book I am using is Combinatorial Game Theory by Aaron N. Siegel) (I didn't really love the Winning Ways book but if it is important then do recommend it below)

Comment: I've read _Lessons in Play_ by Albert, Nowakowski and Wolfe; its more beginner friendly than Siegel's book, while covering a lot of the same ground. Siegel's book is the most modern, streamlined source available, though I believe it has some [mistakes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4789207/strong-version-of-the-number-avoidance-theorem).