# Reference for Combinatorial Game Theory

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, book-recommendation, combinatorial-game-theory

I have become interested in the game of Go and have always loved mathematics. After some reading I have found the subject of combinatorial game theory. I'm looking for a book on the subject with a focus on two player sequential games. Thanks for any help.

Comment: See also [Tutorials for Sprague-Grundy Theorem/Nimbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/43297/26369)

Answer (score 3):

Elwyn R. Berlekamp, John H. Conway, and Richard K. Guy, [Winning Ways for Your Mathematical Plays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_Ways_for_Your_Mathematical_Plays).

Answer (score 1):

Other suggestions besides Winning Ways:

For a "textbook" style introduction, see "Lessons in Play: An introduction to combinatorial game theory" by Wolfe, Albert, Nowakowski.

For a book specific to Go, see "Mathematical Go: Chilling gets the last point" by Berlekamp and Wolfe.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like [Siegel's *Combinatorial game theory*](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-146). It's less "fun" than *Winning Ways*, but by the same token the presentation in WW often feels (to me at least) pretty loose in a way that - especially where "large" infinitary constructions, and ill-founded objects (loopy games) are concerned - I'm not wild about. Siegel's book is a conventional textbook more-or-less, and that does have its advantages.

Comment: Just beware that [not all the exercises are possible to solve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4789207/strong-version-of-the-number-avoidance-theorem/4789763#comment10183967_4789763)

Comment: @MikeEarnest I don't think that's unique to Siegel's book (to put it mildly).